# Using a Ebike controller for a hobby BLDC

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am looking for a BLDC controller around 750W-1000W. I have yet to build the motor itself but am thinking it will fall within the operating range of 48-60v @ 10-15amps. When I look online I notice their are a lot of fairly cheap controllers for E-bikes. Can I just pick one of these up and use one of these with a SMPS? Furthermore - do these e-bike controllers only operate at specific voltages/amps? Or will they work within a range inside of whats advertised (generally speaking)?

Comment: why are you asking us? ... ask the seller for datasheets ... ask them to guarantee operational parameters, with an understanding of a full refund if not met

Comment: I agree with you jsotola....I ask because I am hoping someone else already has experience with this. Not if they can tell me if a specific product from a specific vendor works. For that I would ask the vendor as you stated. But When I searched for 750w+ controllers - I got spammed with 1000s of e bike and scooter controllers. Just wondering if any people are using them - for hobby motors 750W+

Comment: `1000s of e bike and scooter controllers` ... ignore any that have no datasheet available

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just pick one of these up and use one of these with a SMPS?

Probably, provided you build the motor correctly.

Bear in mind that a SMPS generally can't handle current being forced back into it, which happens when the motor is being slowed down by regenerative braking. You may need to put an active clamp across the power supply to stop the voltage from rising.

> will they work within a range inside of whats advertised (generally
> speaking)?

*Generally speaking* a controller will work within its specified voltage range. If single voltages are specified they usually refer to the nominal battery voltage, eg. a 48 V Lithium-ion battery may consist of 13 cells of 3.7 V each nominal, and 4.2 V fully charged for a maximum voltage of 54.6 V. A controller designed for this battery would have to handle at least 54.6 V.

Comment: So far only a few bikes support regenerative braking (none of the center-drive ones, and only some hub-drive ones.) So if you restrict your choices to center-drive then regen isn't an issue.